# Should I be using a service method (which relies on an observable) to do calculations in a component?

Tags: angular, typescript, design-patterns, rxjs, rxjs-observables

This is a pattern I frequently find myself in and I'm not sure why or what the right way to achieve my goals is.

I need a `number` value which many calculations are dependent upon, but this value needs to be retrieved from an observable.

I'm using a get method in the service that my component can call upon, but I always struggle to find the correct pattern to achieve this.

My service method:

```
getMarketCap(company: Company): number {
    combineLatest([
      this.getPrevDayClose(company.ticker),
      this.getCurrDayLastPrice(company.ticker),
      this.getWsLastPrice(company.ticker)
    ]).pipe(
      tap(([prevDayClose, currDayLastPrice, wsLastPrice]) => {
        if (wsLastPrice) {
          this.price = wsLastPrice;
        } else if (currDayLastPrice) {
          this.price = currDayLastPrice;
        } else {
          this.price = prevDayClose;
        }

        return this.price * this.getSharesOutstanding(company);
      })
    );
  }
```

This won't work because the return which includes the value I want is inside the `tap`.

My component is a list of companies and I simply call `this.service.getMarketCap(company)` in `ngOnInit()` for each one. Is there a simple way to get the value of `this.price` out of there after being set, so it can be consumed by other calculation methods in the service?

I've done something like this before with component methods, but I was able to set a variable at the component-level since it was only ever setting for one company at a time.

Is the service the wrong place for this logic?

Comment: If you are on the latest version of Angular, using a Signal would be a great use for this!

Comment: Service is definitely a good place for this - components don't need to be fetching their own data. The signature of `getMarketCap(Company): number` is wrong though (as you point out) - you're (implicitly) returning an `Observable<number>` right now. You could use the "service with a subject" pattern (memoizing calls using a `ReplaySubject` or similar) or, if you're on a new enough version of Angular, you could use a computed singal to avoid the whole `Observable` aspect entirely and work directly with `number`.

Comment: If you leave your service method as-is (but fix the return type to `Observable<number>`) then you can further pipe the result per-company in your component and use the `AsyncPipe` to subscribe in the component template (that would be the recommended RxJS way). Something like `const applePriceDisplay = this.companyService.getMarketPrice({ ticker: 'AAPL'}).pipe(...);` and `<td>{{ applePriceDisplay | async }}</td>`.

Comment: the problem for me with the second comment and using the async pipe (which I'm using in the list component and love) is that I'm not actually sending this directly to the list template - the value for "price" needs to then be consumed by a host of service methods that can calculate a bunch of stuff. Those computed special values will then be rendered in a Material table per company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to get the value of `this.price` out of there after being set, so it can be consumed by other calculation methods in the service?

As D M mentions above, you should have your method return `Observable<number>`.
Then, you can `map` your input observable sources to your "price" value and do your `getSharesOutstanding` work in a separate observable:

```js
  getPrice(ticker: string): Observable<number> {
    return combineLatest([
      this.getPrevDayClose(ticker),
      this.getCurrDayLastPrice(ticker),
      this.getWsLastPrice(ticker),
    ]).pipe(
      map(([prevDayClose, currDayLastPrice, wsLastPrice]) => wsLastPrice ?? currDayLastPrice ?? prevDayClose)
    );
  }

  getMarketCap(company: Company): Observable<number> {
    return this.getPrice(company.ticker).pipe(
      map(price => price * this.getSharesOutstanding(company))
    );
  }
```

Now, other places in your service can use `this.getPrice()` and all of them will be updated when any of the source observables change.

Comment: I probably didn't give enough info in the question, but `this.getSharesOutstanding()` just returns a number, which is the original issue, I can't add an `Observable<number>` and a `number`.

Comment: I assumed `getSharesOutstanding()` returns a number. In `getMarketCap()` we defined observable that starts with `getPrice()` and pipes the value, so inside of the `map`, `price` is a plain number, which gets multiplied by the number returned from `getSharesOutstanding`.  Make sense?

Comment: I see now. So would that mean that I'd have to keep cascading the return of an `Observable<number>` all through the remaining functions, and then async the 10 results or so in the template? Is that the pattern I'm shooting for?

Comment: Probably something like that.  If your sources are observables, it's usually best to keep all your methods returning observables, rather than to explicitly call .subscribe(), then stash the data in a different variable.  Here are a few answers that deal with this topic of composing observables: [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66872283/1858357), [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69688433/1858357), [Answer 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67120069/1858357)

Comment: Also, if the 10 or so data points are related, it *might* be convenient to put a method in your service that emits an object with all data points.  Then, in your component, you'd only need a single `async` pipe.

Comment: so using this "observable cascade" pattern has the api being called like 12 times for each company - is there any way around that?

Comment: You can probably avoid that by appending `shareReplay(1)` to some of your observables.  If that's not enough info to get you going, post another question with your code that is making the duplicate calls.